# ValueError: Can't convert non-rectangular Python sequence to Tensor

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I want to change list to tensor with `tf.convert_to_tensor`, data is following:

```
data=[

array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
   0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
   0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
   0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
   0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
   0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
   1., 0., 0.]), 
array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0.]), 
array([0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
   0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
   0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
   0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
   0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
   0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.,
   0., 0., 0.]), 
array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.])
    ]
```

it didn't work, system says:

> ValueError: Can't convert non-rectangular Python sequence to Tensor.

how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 36):

I'm not sure whether they exist in TensorFlow 1 but TensorFlow 2.0 supports RaggedTensors, which the documentation describes as "... the TensorFlow equivalent of nested variable-length lists."

I think it would be trivial to convert your data to RaggedTensors. It might even be as easy as:

```py
data_tensor = tf.ragged.constant(data)
```

**Example:**

```
>>> a = tf.ragged.constant([[1],[2,3]])
>>> a
<tf.RaggedTensor [[1], [2, 3]]>
```

Comment: ragged tensor indeed will add padding zeros?

Comment: Not by default, no. Check out the documentation: https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/ragged_tensor

Answer (score 11):

You can't. Like the error message says, TensorFlow arrays can not have different sizes along one dimension. Try to use a list of TensorFlow arrays instead or the dataset api.

Comment: Here is one example I gave of using the tf.data.Dataset API, but the tensors were all the same shape:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/66175008/12763497