# Append tensor to each element of another tensor

Tags: python, pytorch

I have a pytorch tensor: `x = torch.zeros(2, 2)`, and another tensor of variable values: `item = torch.tensor([[1, 2], [3, 4]])`, I am just giving this tensor for example.

I would like add the `item` tensor as each element of the x tensor, such that

```
x = [[item, item], 
     [item, item]]
```

So x is a tensor with tensors inside it.
I have tried assigning `item` directly to x, but got an error: `RuntimeError: The expanded size of the tensor must match the existing size at non-singleton dimension`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [`torch.repeat()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.repeat),
your `target_tensor` shape will be `torch.Size([2, 2, 2, 2])`.

`item` tensor shape is already `torch.Size([2, 2])`

use :

```
target_tensor = item.repeat(2, 2, 1, 1)
```

the first two parameters of the repeat() function are x's shape

Answer (score 1):

Didn't see any function native to `pytorch` for this but you can use `np.block`:

```
import numpy as np
item = np.array(item) # need to convert item from tensor to ndarray
x = np.block([[item, item], [item, item]]
x = torch.from_numpy(x) # if you want to change it back to tensor
```

might not be the fastest if it's really big sinec you're converting between the types a lot. Note in this way there's no need to inialize `x` with zeros.

Answer (score 0):

Only Variables support sliced assignment.  The shape must be the same between the source and target.

```
 a=tf.Variable([[1,2],[3,4]])
 a.assign([[5,6], [7,8]])

 print(a.numpy())
```

output:
[[5,6]
[7 8]]

if the data is an non-regular assignment try a raggedtensor

[ValueError: Can't convert non-rectangular Python sequence to Tensor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56304986/valueerror-cant-convert-non-rectangular-python-sequence-to-tensor)

```
data_tensor=tf.ragged.constant([[1, 2], [3, 4,5]])
print(data_tensor)
```

output

```
<tf.RaggedTensor [[1, 2], [3, 4, 5]]>
```